# SQL SELECT or INSERT INTO query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm working with SQL Server 2000. I need to take the results from one column (`VALIMIT`) and insert them into another column (`VALIMIT2012`) in the same table (`lending_limits`).

My question is do I need to do a `SELECT` query first, or do I just start with an `INSERT INTO` query and what the proper syntax would be for the `INSERT INTO` query.

Comment: There is no `MS SQL 2003` - do you mean **MS Access 2003**, or do you mean a **SQL Server** version (valid values: 7, 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) statement:

```
update lending_limits
set VALIMIT2012 = VALIMIT
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this won't remove the results from VALIMIT?  Both columns VALIMIT and VALIMIT2012 will return the same results after the UPDATE / SET query?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You don't insert columns, you insert rows, so what you want is an `update`:

```
update SomeTable
set VALIMIT2012 = VALIMIT
```

Note: It looks like you have one column per year, which is bad database design. If you have different data for each year, you should put that in a separate table, so that you get the year as data, not part of the column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName SET VALIMIT2012 = VALIMIT
```